# TimeSlider Plugin and Leaflet - Markers not appearing in order

Tags: javascript, leaflet, ui-leaflet

Updated with a [JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/ngeLm8c0/3/)

I am using LeafletJS to build a web map with a timeline slider. I am using the [LeafletSlider plugin](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider)  to show a group of markers based on a GEOJSON property named `DATE_START`. Here's an example of what my data object looks like:

```
var camps = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "STATUS": "UNOCCUPIED",
            "DATE_START": "2015-06-23",
            "DATE_CLOSED": "2016-01-23"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [64.6875, 34.97600151317591]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "STATUS": "OCCUPIED",
            "DATE_START": "2014-01-21",
            "DATE_CLOSED": "2015-05-25"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [65.335693359375, 36.26199220445664]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "STATUS": "UNOCCUPIED",
            "DATE_START": "2015-09-13",
            "DATE_CLOSED": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [67.587890625, 35.969115075774845]
        }
    }]
};
```

An example of my code:

```
//Create a marker layer (in the example done via a GeoJSON FeatureCollection)
var testlayer = L.geoJson(camps, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.DATE_START);
    }
});

var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
    position: "topright",
    layer: testlayer,
    timeAttribute: 'DATE_START'
});

//Make sure to add the slider to the map ;-)
map.addControl(sliderControl);

//And initialize the slider
sliderControl.startSlider();
```

I've added the timeslider plugin to my map, and although it's functioning, I can't seem to get the slider to show the markers in a temporal order. For example, the marker with the `DATE_START` value of `2014-01-21` is shown second when in fact it should be shown first because it's the marker with the earliest date.

**How can I get my timeslider/markers to appear in the correct order from earliest to latest? Thanks.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As [ghybs mentions below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878087/timeslider-plugin-and-leaflet-markers-not-appearing-in-order/35881206#comment59430908_35881206) (and shows in [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ngeLm8c0/5/)), the proper way to ensure that the slider returns data in the correct order is to sort the `options.markers` array of the sliderControl:

```
sliderControl.options.markers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.feature.properties.DATE_START > b.feature.properties.DATE_START);
});
```

My original answer (below) sorts the features of the GeoJSON, but this does not guarantee that Leaflet will return them in the correct order.

---

**Original answer:**

You can use the [`array.sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort the `features` array in place:

```
camps.features.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a.properties.DATE_START > b.properties.DATE_START);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/ngeLm8c0/4/

Comment: To be rigorous, the sorting should be performed within the Slider Control's `options.markers` array. Indeed, the plugin extracts the given layer individual features using `eachLayer()` method, which does not guarantee the order. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ngeLm8c0/5/

Comment: Learning so much from you guys. Thanks!